# The $k$th derivative of $\sin^n x$ as $n \ \sin^{n - k} x$ times a polynomial in $\cos x$

Tags: derivatives

It seems the $k$th derivative of the function $x \mapsto \sin^n x$ can be expressed as $n \ \sin^{n - k} x$ times a polynomial with only even or only odd powers of $\cos x$ (depending on the parity of $k$), with polynomials in $n$ as coefficients, for natural $k$ and integer $n$ and complex $x$.

The highest term is $n^{k-1} \cos^k x$; the ranks of the other polynomial-in-$n$ coefficients for $\cos^{k-2j} x$ seem to be (maximally) $(k-1-j)$.

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^0}{\mathrm{d}x^0} \sin^n x = n \ \sin^{n - 0} x \ \left(n^{-1} \cos^0 x\right)\text{ for }n \neq 0
$$
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^1}{\mathrm{d}x^1} \sin^n x = n \ \sin^{n - 1} x \ \left(n^0 \cos x\right)
$$
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}x^2} \sin^n x = n \ \sin^{n - 2} x \ \left(n^1 \cos^2 x - 1\right)
$$
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^3}{\mathrm{d}x^3} \sin^n x = n \ \sin^{n - 3} x \ \left(n^2 \cos^3 x + (-3 n + 2) \cos x\right)
$$
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^4}{\mathrm{d}x^4} \sin^n x = n \ \sin^{n - 4} x \ \left(n^3 \cos^4 x + (-6 n^2 + 8 n - 4) \cos^2 x + (3 n - 2)\right)
$$
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^5}{\mathrm{d}x^5} \sin^n x = n \ \sin^{n - 5} x
$$
$$
\left(n^4 \cos^5 x + (-10 n^3 + 20 n^2 - 20 n + 8) \cos^3 x + (15 n^2 - 30 n + 16) \cos x\right)
$$
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^6}{\mathrm{d}x^6} \sin^n x = n \ \sin^{n - 6} x
$$
$$\left(n^5 \cos^6 x + (-15 n^4 + 40 n^3 - 60 n^2 + 48 n - 16) \cos^4 x + (45 n^3 - 150 n^2 + 196 n - 88) \cos^2 x + (-15 n^2 + 30 n - 16)\right)
$$

Is there a general rule to determine the polynomial-in-$n$ coefficients?

**Edit:**

The [OEIS sequence A133341](http://oeis.org/A133341) seems to determine the second polynomial-in-$n$ coefficients (when one alternates the signs, and discards the italic values):

- *1*,
- *2*,
- 1, *3*,
- 3, 2, *4*,
- 6, 8, 4, *5*,
- 10, 20, 20, 8, *6*,
- 15, 40, 60, 48, 16, *7*,
- 21, 70, 140, 168, 112, 32, *8*,
- 28, 112, 280, 448, 448, 256, 64, *9*,
- 36, 168, 504, 1008, 1344, 1152, 576, 128, *10*,
- 45, 240, 840, 2016, 3360, 3840, 2880, 1280, 256, …

Comment: Are you familiar with complex numbers?

Comment: Yes, but I fail to see the connection between this question and complex numbers. Feel free to explain if you have found one.

Comment: One way to get a formula for the $i$-th derivative would be the Faà di Bruno's formula. It's all but nice though

Comment: Statement of Theorem 1.2 is, I believe, what you are seeking, its associated proof on page 10 will help.  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.1205.pdf

Comment: @Kevin Interestingly, at the top of page 12 another solution for d^m/dx^m sin^ℓ  x in another form is deduced from Faà di Bruno's formula, with ℓ+1 cosines and ℓ+1 sines (which presumably cancel each other out for real x, given that they are multiplied with the imaginary unit). The cosines and sines are not raised to any power, they have arguments different from x though.

Comment: What you need is the generalised product rule, for taking the $m$th derivative of a product of $n$ factors. It's similar to the polynomial expansion formula. However, since all your factors here are equal, there should be nice simplifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer has since been written out in: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.01386.pdf . For the expressions with these polynomials, skip the section “Using the complex definitions and the binomial theorem”.

**Determining $p_{k}(n)(\cos x)$ recursively**

When, for natural $k$, and integer $n$, and complex $x$,
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^k}{\mathrm{d}x^k} \sin^n x = \sin^{n - k} x \ p_{k}(n)(\cos x)
$$
with $p_{k}(n)(\cos x)$ a polynomial in $\cos x$ with only terms with even powers of $\cos x$ when $k$ is even, and only terms with odd powers of $\cos x$ when $k$ is odd; with $n^k \cos^k x$ as the highest term;

and note that each coefficient of $p_{k}(n)(\cos x)$ includes the initial factor $n$ that I factored out in the question;

then
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^{k+1}}{\mathrm{d}x^{k+1}} \sin^n x = \sin^{n - (k+1)} x \ \left( ((n - k) \cos x) \ p_{k}(n)(\cos x) + (\cos^2 x - 1) \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\cos x} p_{k}(n)(\cos x)\right)
$$
with $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\cos x} p_{k}(n)(\cos x)$ a polynomial in $\cos x$ with only terms with odd powers of $\cos x$ when $k$ is odd, and only terms with even powers of $\cos x$ when $k$ is even; with $k \ n \ \cos^{k-1} x$ as the highest term.

So
$$
p_{k+1}(n)(\cos x) = ((n - k) \cos x) \ p_{k}(n)(\cos x) + (\cos^2 x - 1) \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\cos x} p_{k}(n)(\cos x)
$$
is a polynomial in $\cos x$ with only terms with odd powers of $\cos x$ when $k$ is even, and only terms with even powers of $\cos x$ when $k$ is odd; with $((n - k)^1 \ n^k  + k \ n) \ \cos^{k+1} x = n^{k+1} \ \cos^{k+1} x$ as the highest term.

**Furthermore**

For the same polynomials $p_{k}(n)(y)$ also holds
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^k}{\mathrm{d}x^k} \cos^n x = (-1)^{k} \cos^{n - k} x \ p_{k}(n)(\sin x)
$$
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^k}{\mathrm{d}x^k} \sinh^n x = \sinh^{n - k} x \ p_{k}(n)(\cosh x)
$$